# Using checkboxes to add quantity to cart with

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, shopify, liquid

Working on a product page where multiple products are offered up. Checkboxes are used to select up to 3 products at which point they can be added to the cart - pulling products from the store inventory.

All is working fine - except I cannot figure out the jQuery to connect the checkbox directly to a quantity of 1 for the product once the add to cart is resolved.

Here is my code snippet in Liquid on Shopify:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
//<![CDATA[
// Including jQuery conditionally
if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
    document.write({{ "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" | script_tag | json }});
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();<\/script>');
}
//]]>
</script>

<script>
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(e){
   if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 3) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false)
        alert("Sorry you may only select up to three!");
   }
 
});
  
{% assign linklist = linklists['order-form'] %}
var length = {{ linklist.links.size }};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#quantity-0").focus();    
    $("#submit-table").click(function(e) {     
        e.preventDefault();
        //array for Variant Titles
        var toAdd = new Array();
        var qty ;
        for(i=0; i < length; i++){
        
            toAdd.push({
                variant_id: $("#variant-"+i).val(),        
                quantity_id: $("#quantity-"+i).val() || 0
            });
        }
      
        function moveAlong(){
            if (toAdd.length) {
                var request = toAdd.shift();
                var tempId= request.variant_id;
                var tempQty = request.quantity_id;
                var params = {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/cart/add.js',
                    data: 'quantity='+tempQty+'&id='+tempId,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(line_item) { 
                        //console.log("success!");
                        moveAlong();

                    },
                    error: function() {
                        //console.log("fail");
                        moveAlong();
                        
                    }
                };
                $.ajax(params);
            }
            else {              
                document.location.href = '/cart';
            }  
        };
        moveAlong();
    });
});

</script>
```

And here is product page script for the actual list:

```html
{% assign linklist = linklists['order-form'] %}
<form>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">  
        <tbody>
            <tr id="cart-headlines">
                <td class="cart-thumb">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="cart-title">Product Title</td>     
                <td class="cart-unitprice">Price</td>                       
                <td class="cart-quantity">Select</td>                 
            </tr>
            {% for link in linklist.links %}    
            <tr>
                <td >
                    <a href="" title="View Page">
                        <img src="{{ link.object.featured_image | product_img_url: 'thumb' }}" alt="{{ link.object.title | escape }}" />
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td >
                    <a href="{{ link.object.url}}" title="View {{item.title | escape }} Page">
                        {{ link.object.title | truncatewords:5 }}
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ link.object.variants.first.price | money }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden"  value="{{ link.object.variants.first.id }}" id="variant-{{ forloop.index0 }}"/>
                 
                    <input type="checkbox"  id="quantity_id" class="single-checkbox" 
       />               </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p style='text-align:right;'>
        <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" id="submit-table"/>
    </p>
</form>
```

Seems like it's close. At the moment - clicking any checkbox adds all products to cart.

I want to click a checkbox and have that translate to 1 quantity for that specific product.

Help much appreciated.

Best

Comment: the script is looking for a value here quantity_id: $("#quantity-"+i).val() but your code doesn't have a #quantity_1 (for example) it only has #quantity_id, Also there is no value set for #quantity_X so when you get the id of the checkbox sorted you'll have to add value="1" to it

Answer (score 0):

Shopify defaults to adding a quantity of one if no quantity is specified, and Shopify has a built-in way of adding multiple products to the cart at the same time as well!

If you do something like this to set up your checkboxes:

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
  <p><label><input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }}</label></p>
{% endfor %}
```

- then the `name="id[]"` (note the square brackets) will tell Shopify to add all of those variant IDs.  Note that Shopify only allows a single quantity field to be used, which will apply to all of the items at the same time - which, in your case, sounds like exactly what you want.

You can see a brief sample at my [test store](https://bold19.myshopify.com/collections/all/products/live-theropod?preview_theme_id=161907598) - I haven't AJAX-ified it, but if you wanted to you'd just need to do something like:

```
jQuery(/* appropriate selector */).on( /* submit or click, as appropriate */, function(evt){

  evt.preventDefault();

  var form = jQuery(evt.target).closest('form');

  /* Any DOM or validation stuff that needs to happen */

  jQuery.ajax({
    url:'/cart/add.js',
    type:'post',
    dataType:'json',
    data:form.serialize(),
    success:function(line_item){
      /* Whatever needs to happen on product add */
    }
  });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note: If you want to post *different* quantities for each of the checked variants you will need to loop through them and make separate AJAX calls.  Posting the *same* quantity for all of them is what allows you to use the `name=id[]` single-call shortcut.